# How read -8v to +2v using ADC ? which ADC i can use?

Tags: adc, atmega

input signal is from +2v to -8v whose time stabilization is 3-8 Sec and frequency is varying from 60 Hz to 100 Hz. How i can read that signal, and which ADC i can use ?

Comment: if you reference the ADC's ground to your negative rail, and use an appropriate resistor divider (and possibly buffer) to bring the voltage range within your ADC's range (say 0 - 3.3v) then it should be easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this, where the Vin of 10 voltsPP becomes 3.3voltsPP at the ADC.
The input_range is set by two factors:

1) the input attenuation of 3:1, caused by R1||R2 being 50Kohm, and the Rin (which is R3) of 100Kohm. The attenuation is 50K/(50K + 100K)

2) the input center voltage (take away R3, and see what is left) of VDD/2
which for VDD of 3.3 volts, we have Vcenter of 1.65 volts

Thus the input range is 1.65 -+ 1.65*3 = 1.65 -+ 5 volts or -3.65v to 6.65v.

You are able to digitize 0/3.3  volts, and also well below ground and well above VDD.

To handle -8v/+2v and EXACTLY fill the ADC's Vin range will require more than this circuit achieves.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGivZt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Perfect solution in my opinion. Linear scaling and even if the signal line gets stuck at -2V or 8V, the resistor network will prevent damage to the ADC input.